# Running PHP in IIS6

Tags: php, iis-6

i am using IIS to run my php website and i configure IIS to work with php as its explained the following tutorial

http://www.wikihow.com/Install-PHP-5-for-IIS-6

but when i run any php page is give me the following error

You have attempted to execute a CGI, ISAPI, or other executable program from a directory that does not allow programs to be executed.

i follow this https://serverfault.com/questions/251499/error-when-installing-php5-on-iis6/252149#252149

now i am getting the following error message

FastCGI Error

### The FastCGI Handler was unable to process the request.

Error Details:

Could not find entry for "php" on site 67761686 in [Types] section. 
Error Number: 1413 (0x80070585). 
Error Description: Invalid index. 
HTTP Error 500 - Server Error.
Internet Information Services (IIS)

here is my updated fcgiext.ini

```
[Types]
php=PHP

[PHP]
ExePath=C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe
```

now i am getting this error message

```
The FastCGI Handler was unable to process the request. 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Error Details:

The FastCGI process exceeded configured request timeout 
Error Number: 258 (0x80070102). 
Error Description: The wait operation timed out.
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this link would help

http://www.ardamis.com/2009/02/15/php-pages-return-a-404-error-on-iis/

> Open iis.msc again, go back to the Home Directory tab, and select the “Scripts only” option >from the Execute Permissions menu. Restart the server.
>
> The server should now be correctly processing .php files.

Comment: I did some Googling and it's certainly IIS permission thing.
Make sure the folders+files and OFC php.exe has the correct permission.

Comment: To modify the Execute permissions, right-click the directory in Microsoft Management Console (MMC), click Properties, click the Directory tab, and make sure that the Execute Permissions setting is appropriate for the content that you are trying to access.

Answer (score 1):

PHP pages return a 404 error on IIS

I was installing PHP 5 on an IIS 6 server when I ran into what turns out to be a pretty common problem. PHP appeared to be installed correctly, but browsing to any page with a .php extension returned a 404 Page Not Found error. While the steps below fixed this for me, I had to piece them together from a few different sources, and a number of other suggestions (like copying the php.ini file to C:/WINDOWS/) didn’t work and were not necessary.

Open your IIS management console at C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\iis.msc.
Drill down to your web site, right-click and select Properties.
Select the Home Directory tab, then click on the Configuration button.
Select the Mappings tab.
 If you don’t see a .php extension listed, click the Add button. Browse to the PHP 5 DLL (which may be at C:\Program Files\PHP\php5isapi.dll). Type .php into the Extension field and leave everything else at the default values. Click OK. The extension and executable path will be filled out and under Verbs you should see “All”.

I should point out that I didn’t have anything listed under the ISAPI Filters tab.

Stop and restart your IIS server and browse to a .php file. (To restart your IIS server, open the IIS management console, right-click the local computer in the left pane, hover on All Tasks and choose Restart IIS.) Chances are, you’re no longer getting the 404 error, but are now seeing a 403.1 message, like:

```
The page cannot be displayed
You have attempted to execute a CGI, ISAPI, or other executable program from a directory that does not allow programs to be executed.

Please try the following:

* Contact the Web site administrator if you believe this directory should allow execute access.

HTTP Error 403.1 – Forbidden: Execute access is denied.
Internet Information Services (IIS)
```

Open iis.msc again, go back to the Home Directory tab, and select the “Scripts only” option from the Execute Permissions menu. Restart the server.

The server should now be correctly processing .php files.

Comment: getting same error as previous after the above steps have you restarted your IIS ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my answer on Server Fault for a fairly bulletproof way to install PHP in under ten minutes:

> [Error When Installing PHP5 on IIS6](https://serverfault.com/questions/251499/error-when-installing-php5-on-iis6/252149#252149)

If you follow **all** of the steps in the correct order you'll have PHP up and running in no time.

**Updated:**

As per your comment and question update, edit your `fcgiext.ini` file so that it only contains the following lines:

```
[Types]
php=PHP

[PHP]
ExePath=C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe
```

Comment: @meera - ok...this is progress can you post a copy of what's in your `%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\fcgiext.ini` file?

Comment: @Kev plzz could you reply me because i did a lot of research but i did not get solution for my issue

Comment: @meera - my apologies, I missed that. Will have a look.

Comment: @meera - looks like you didn't edit the fcgiext.ini file as per the instructions in that linked answer. I have updated my answer. You must follow all of those steps exactly as described.

Comment: @meera - there's two mistakes. You have leading commas before the `[Types]` and `[PHP]` section names. Just delete everything in the fcgiext.ini file and replace with exactly what I posted in my answer.

Comment: @Kev you mean you just adding these two lines [Types] php=PHP [PHP] ExePath=C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe

Comment: @meera - just select all and delete everything inside fcgiext.ini, then paste those 4 lines EXACTLY as described above.

Comment: @Kev i delete everything and past the four lines but now it giving me a differen error

Comment: @meera - can you now update your question with that you have in the fcgiext.ini file AND  the error message you're now getting?

Comment: @meera - and this is what you get from running the test script that just prints the `phpinfo();` page?

Comment: @Kev yes i create a page test.php and add the following line <?php     phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: @meera - very odd, you're defintely on the right track. Ok...here's a stab in the dark....is Windows Firewall running on this server?

Comment: @Kev yes i have firewall in that server but its off

Comment: @meera - can you change your test.php file and replace `phpinfo();` with `echo "hello world";`.

Comment: @meera - I could RDP to your server if you felt I was trustworthy :)

Comment: @Kev you mean Remote Desktop access? sorry i can not because its not my own server its my work server

Comment: @Kev i am still having the porblem but any way thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following from the command prompt:

1.

```
 cd c:\Windows\system32\inetsrv
```

2.

```
   c:\Windows\system32\inetsrv>cscript fcgiconfig.js -add -section:"PHP" -extension:php -path:"c:\php\php-cgi.exe"
```